# Parametrization of a surface

Tags: geometry

I am given the curve $ a (u) = (\cos(u), \sin(u), u) $. I am asked to write the parametrization of the surface obtained intersecting this curve with lines orthogonal to the z axis. How to do this? Should I consider the parametrization of a generical line orthogonal to the z axis and somehow compose the two parametrizations?

Comment: Intersecting a curve with a bunch of lines can never give more than the original curve, i.e. can't give a surface. So perhaps you want the surface formed by all those lines which are intersect your curve and also intersect the $z$ axis at a right angle? Please clarify.

Comment: Exactly that. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on $u$ you have a point $a(u)$ in space. Now you are interested in the line which intersects both this point and the $z$ axis, the latter at a right angle. For an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$, the perpendicular through that point to the $z$ axis can be described as the set of points

$$(0,0,z)+v(x,y,0)=(vx,vy,z)$$

For the specific case of $(x,y,z)=a(u)$ you get

$$(0,0,u)+v(\cos u,\sin u,0)=(v\cos u,v\sin u, u)$$

as a possible parametrization of the [helicoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid).

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would say, the surface be the "helicoid":

When $a (u) = (\cos u, \sin u, u)$, then $s(u,v)=(v\cos u, v\sin u, u)$ (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid  ).

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Still, I can't understand how to obtain this parametrization. Is he considering $ b (v) = (v, v, 0) $ and then combines (multiplies) the two? Why?

Comment: @user3461126: The parametric equation of each straight line orthogonal to the axis z, through the points $(0,0,u_0), (\cos u_0, \sin u_0, u_0)$ is 

$x=v\cos u_0,\,y=v\sin u_0,\,z = u_0,\,v\in (-\infty, \infty)$, for constant $u_0$. 

For variable parameter u get the equation search area:

$x=v\cos u,\,y=v\sin u,\,z = u,\,\,u,v\in (-\infty, \infty)$.